# HTML/CSS code issues for smaller screens

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with my code when I set my display for small screens. I need the aside gone but the yellow background still shows. Also the logo buttom (hamburger menu) should float to the top right and not scrunch up the header.

This is my first post, thank you in advanced.

Here is the HTML code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Eating Well in Season</title>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="modernizr.custom.40753.js"></script>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <script src="respond.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
      <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/android.png">
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="header-nav-container">
         <p class="skipnavigation"><a href="contentstart">Skip navigation</a></p>
         <header>
            <h1>Eating Well in Season</h1>
             <div>
               <img src="images/logo.png" width="216" height="146" alt="">
            </div>
         </header>
         <nav class="sitenavigation">
            <div><img src="images/menu.png" width="63" height="57" alt="Show Navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sources.html">Sources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="menus.html">Sample Menus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
         </nav>
           </div>
      <div class="article-aside-outer-container">
         <div class="article-aside-inner-container">
            <article id="contentstart">
               <figure>
                  <img src="images/meal.jpg" width="450" height="299" alt="a dish containing fusilli pasta topped with chunks of grilled chicken and grilled squash,  green peas, shredded asiago cheese, and sprigs of mint">
                  <figcaption>Healthy meals.</figcaption>
               </figure>
               <figure>
                  <img src="images/veggies.jpg" width="450" height="298" alt="a woven basket containing beets, a bunch of radishes with greens, cucumbers, a bunch of green onions, and parsley">
                  <figcaption>Local sources.</figcaption>
               </figure>
               <figure>
                  <img src="images/delivery.jpg" width="450" height="299" alt="a box truck driving down a highway with buildings in the background">
                  <figcaption>Your schedule.</figcaption>
               </figure>
            </article>
            <aside>
               <h2>What&rsquo;s In Season</h2>
               <p>Baby Carrots</p>
               <p>Cardoons</p>
               <p>Chard</p>
               <p>Fiddleheads</p>
               <p>Mint</p>
               <p>Morels</p>
               <p>New Potatoes</p>
               <p>Ramps</p>
            </aside>
         </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
         <p>Eating Well in Season &bull; Glover, VT &bull; (802) 555-3947</p>
      </footer>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am having issues with my code when I set my display for small screens. I need the aside gone but the yellow background still shows. Also the logo buttom (hamburger menu) should float to the top right and not scrunch up the header.

This is my first post, thank you in advanced.

Here is the CSS code.

```
/* reset styles */

html {
    font-size: 20px;
}
a,
article,
body,
div,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
h1,
h2,
h3,
img,
li,
nav,
p,
section,
ul {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
/* body and page container */

body {
    font-family: "Alegreya Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.header-nav-container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #a17f43;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
.article-aside-outer-container {
    background-color: #aabd7e;
}
.article-aside-inner-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(246, 224, 65);
}
p {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
/* skip navigation link */

p.skipnavigation a {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}
p.skipnavigation a:focus {
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: auto;
    right: 1em;
    top: 1em;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    z-index: 2;
}
/* header section */

header {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #a17f43;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
}
header h1 {
    margin: 1.2em 3% 0 3%;
    color: rgb(246, 224, 65);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 2.9em;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    float: right;
}
header div {
    float: right;
    margin: 2% 0 1%;
    width: 26%;
}
/* site navigation */

nav.sitenavigation {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-top: 3.4em;
    background-color: #a17f43;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
.navigation-menu-button {
    display: none;
}
nav.sitenavigation li {
    margin: 0.5em;
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: .8em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
nav.sitenavigation a {
    padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: .6em;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:link {
    color: rgb(246, 224, 65);
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:visited {
    color: #eee;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:hover,
nav.sitenavigation a:focus {
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(246, 224, 65);
}
nav.sitenavigation a:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
}
/* main content */

article {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    background-color: floralwhite;
}
article h2 {
    margin: 0.4em 0.4em 0;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
article h3 {
    margin: 0.4em 0.4em 0;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
article div p {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
article p {
    margin: 0 1em 0.4em 1.4em;
}
figure {
    width: 33.3333%;
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
figure:first-of-type {
    background-image: url("images/meal.jpg");
}
figure:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background-image: url("images/veggies.jpg");
}
figure:last-of-type {
    background-image: url("images/delivery.jpg");
}
figure img {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
figcaption {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.25em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
/* sidebar */

aside {
    width: 15%;
    padding: 2%;
    float: right;
}
aside h2 {
    padding: 0.4em;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
aside p {
    padding-left: 1.4em;
}
/* footer section */

footer {
    padding: 0.6em;
    background-color: black;
    color: floralwhite;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
footer p {
    margin: 0.4em;
}
/*standard screen styles */

@media screen and (max-width: 1500px),
print {
    header {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
    }
    header h1 {
        margin: 2% 4% 1%;
        float: left;
    }
    nav.sitenavigation {
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
    }
}
/* small screen/tablet styles */

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px),
print {
    article {
        width: 62%;
    }
    figure {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        background-image: none;
        float: none;
    }
    figure img {
        display: block;
    }
    aside {
        width: 33.5%;
    }
}
/* handheld styles */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    header {
        margin: 0 95px 0 0;
        float: left;
    }
    header h1 {
        width: auto;
        margin: .4em 2%;
        float: left;
    }
    header div {
        display: none;
    }
    nav.sitenavigation {
        margin: 16px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .navigation-menu-button {
        display: block;
        float: right;
    }
    nav.sitenavigation ul {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 73px;
        right: 6px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    nav.sitenavigation li {
        margin: 0;
        border: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    nav.sitenavigation {
        width: 83%;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    aside {
        display: none;
    }
}
/* print styles */

@media print {
    article,
    article h2,
    aside,
    body,
    .container,
    footer,
    header,
    header h1,
    header p {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
    header {
        margin: 0 0 1em;
    }
    header div {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    header h1 {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    nav {
        display: none;
    }
    figure {
        border: 3px solid #000;
    }
}
@page {
    margin: 0.5in;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I would liek to post my CSS but it is telling me it is too long.

Comment: Try posting a message above the css describing what it does, and that may make the error go away.

Comment: Not sure I understand.

Comment: You wrote a big message above your html code. Do the same for CSS.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Comment: The ``.article-aside-inner-container`` div has a yellow background but your media queries never affect that div. Is that div the problem?

Comment: I feel like it might be. The fotn dissapears but the yellow background stays.